# How to arrange tags with json2html

Tags: html, json, json2html

I'm using json2html and trying to work out an issue where I want to write transform code to give me the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div><b>Bold text</b> plus plain text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which results in this output:      **Bold text** plus plain text

What I have currently is this:

```
{"tag":"div","children":[
    {"tag":"b","html":"Bold text"}
],"html":" plus plain text"}
```

But this reverses the order of my text:        plus plain text **Bold text**

I tried to switch the positioning of my transform code to this:

```
{"tag":"b","children":[
    {"tag":"div","html":" plus plain text"}
],"html":"Bold text"}
```

This corrected the positioning problem, but all of the text was bold instead of just part of it. Any suggestions for how I can rearrange things to get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

json2html doesn't have support (yet) for mixing markup with plain text, in other words a bold markup beside plain text like so:

```
<div><b>Bold text</b> plus plain text</div>
```

however you can easily get around this by wrapping the plain text in a span element like this

```
<div><b>Bold text</b><span>plus plain text</span></div>
```

which would look like this in a transform

```
{"tag":"div","children":[
   {"tag":"b","html":"Bold text"},
   {"tag":"span","html":" plus plain text"}
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `b` tag and the subsequent plain text to be children of the `div` tag, you should make them both children of the `div` tag:

```
{"tag":"div","children":[
    {"tag":"b","html":"Bold text"}, 
    {"tag": "span", "html":" plus plain text"}
]}
```